# Only Bottom div updates mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, href, sql-update

I have no idea why but only the bottom div works the code is:

```
  <div id = "Travel_Base">
  <a href="camp.php" > Travel dfgdsgdfg?</a>
  <?php $UpdateLocation = mysql_query("UPDATE locations SET Zelk_Camp = 1, Zelk_Mines = 0,Zelk_CrashSite = 0 WHERE name='$name'"); ?>
  </div>

  <div id = "Travel_Mine">
  <a href="camp.php" >Travel skbgfshflgdgdf? </a>
  <?php $UpdateLocation = mysql_query("UPDATE locations SET Zelk_Camp = 0, Zelk_Mines = 1,Zelk_CrashSite = 0 WHERE name='$name1'"); ?>
  </div>
```

both divs are to decide a location of a player, the player will be at which location is = 1 but when i click the mine link it will take me to the mines, but not the other way.  so only the bottom div works.

The divs are initially hidden and then appear when i click on a certain image if that affects it.

All answers are welcome sorry if too vague first question ever.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `$name1` in the second query be `$name`?

Comment: What happends when the first div is clicked?

Comment: @Kirster Yeah it probably would i was just checking a few things. 
Araw when the first div is clicked it goes to 'camp.php' but doesn't update the database like i want it o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay sussed a way to do with out ajax, the code is this what i used in case anyone else comes across same problem.

```
 <div id = "TravelBase">
  <?php $Base = '<a href="Location_ZelkCamp.php" > Travel to Planet Zelk Base Camp?</a>';
        $BaseCurrent = '<a href="Location_ZelkCamp.php"> Planet Zelk Base Camp is your current location.</a>';

  $Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE name='$Basename'");
        if($Basename  = mysql_fetch_array($Query))
        if($Basename ['Zelk_Camp'] == 0)

 echo $Base;

  else

  echo $BaseCurrent;


  ?>
  </div>

 <div id = "TravelMine">

  <?php $Mine = '<a href="Location_ZelkMine.php" > Travel to Planet Zelk Mine?</a>';
        $MineCurrent = '<a href="Location_ZelkMine.php">Planet Zelk Mine is your current location.</a>';

   $Query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE name='$Minename'");
        if($Minename = mysql_fetch_array($Query))
        if($Minename ['Zelk_Mines'] == 0)

 echo $Mine;

  else

  echo $MineCurrent;

  ?>
  </div>
```

Thats one file but then you have in another file

```
<? include_once("connect.php"); ?>
<?php require("Safe.php"); ?>

<?php $UpdateLocation = mysql_query("UPDATE locations SET Zelk_Camp = 1, Zelk_Mines = 0,Zelk_CrashSite = 0 WHERE name='$name'"); ?>

  <?  header( 'Location: Camp.php' ) ; ?>
```

This is the update mysql file then header changes my page.
You load the php file in this line ' Travel to Planet Zelk Base Camp?';'

Thanks for everyone who helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Your query (update) will always return 1 so the second $UpdateLocation  will get the value of 1 before page load.

Second will always show

Comment: is there is way for me to only update when i click the specific href?

Comment: Maybe use AJAX? onclick(makeajaxcall())

Comment: Have no experience in AJAX would have no idea where to start tbh

Comment: What will it do for me exactly? like what am i meant to replace? the href? or the update?

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken if you want your update to occur when you click your links, or when your div are shown. Your PHP / MySQL queries and your HTML page operate in different contexts, so currently both your requests are sent when the page is loaded, and clicking any link won't change anything. (Additionnally, you seem to be using two similarly named variables, $name and $name1)

If you want to update you database when clicking your links without changing page, you'll have to do an ajax call to a PHP file executing your query. 
If you want to do that update when you go to camp.php, just put a parameter in the url querystring and do your request depending on that parameter.

Comment: i want to do it before i change the page so i think the Ajax call to php is on the cards, so how do i go about doing this if you dont mind? as i said earlier no experience in ajax